# Should I marry my US fiance in the UK or US, if we wish to reside in the US after marriage?

Tags: visas, legal, weddings

I have a number of questions that will help me understand if I should  marry my US fiance in the UK or US, if we want to settle in the US.

1. Firstly, from a timeframe and financial perspective, should I (British citizen) marry my US fiancè in the US or UK, if we wish to reside in the US after marriage?

**If UK:**

(Working on the basis that my foreign national fiancè will enter the UK to marry on a Marriage Visitor visa)...

2. Based on the rule that you must give at least 28 days notice to marry at a UK Register Office, must my foreign national fiancè stay in the UK between giving notice at the Register Office, and the date of the ceremony (minimum 28 days later). Or is he able to exit and re-enter the country during this time? I.e to continue employment in his current place of residence.
3. Based on the Marriage Visitor visa period of 6 months:

a. Can my foreign national fiancè stay in the UK beyond the day of marriage on the existing Marriage Visitor visa (for a period up to 6 months)?

b. If yes, and once married, can he exit and re-enter the UK on the same Marriage Visitor visa (within the 6 month visa period) for the purpose of continued employment in his place of residence?

4. Once married, and once the 6 month Marriage Visitor visa has expired, on what visa type can my foreign national husband visit the UK? (whilst we await the US CR-1 Spousal Visa allowing me to move permanent to the US to be approved).

**IF US**

1. a. Can my British wife travel to US for visitation, while the CR-1 Spousal Visa is in process, without causing complications?

b. If yes, on what visa type?

Comment: Another option is to get a K-1 fiance visa for your fiance to marry in the US and do Adjustment of Status.

Comment: Not only is this kind of question (long term travel) not covered on this part of stack exchange, but additionally your ask a whole string of question which is typically not appropriate for stack exchange with unpaid volunteers/helpers. For such a write-up with multiple scenarios, you have to pay a lawyer.